# Frame rate (interval) issues in recording GL rendering with a GLSurfaceView using MediaCodec

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview, grafika

I've been developing a recording component of our app, which records GL renderings on a GLSurfaceView using MediaCodec and Muxer.  I found a nice set of examples by fadden (like [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) and Grafika...  Thanks so much fadden), and tried those stuff out.  I've built a recorder based on the game recording model of Android Breakout, because our app used GLSurfaceView to do the rendering.

It seemed working well on my Nexus 7 (2013 with 4.4.2 and 5.0.2).  I was able to record rendered screens, and those encoded MP4s were played well on other devices.  However, when a bit more complicated rendering got involved, it started dropping frames.  Well, it's not that complicated, as it takes only around 4 ms to render the frame.  So, I've been trying to identify the source of the problem.

My pseudo code are very similar to the Android Breakout Recorder.  OnDrawFrame() looks like the following.

```
    GLES20.glViewport(mViewportXoff, mViewportYoff, mViewportWidth, mViewportHeight);
    drawFrame();

    GameRecorder recorder = GameRecorder.getInstance();
    if (recorder.isRecording() && recordThisFrame()) {
        saveRenderState();

        // switch to recorder state
        recorder.makeCurrent();
        recorder.getProjectionMatrix(mProjectionMatrix);
        recorder.setViewport();

        // render everything again
        drawFrame();
        recorder.swapBuffers();

        restoreRenderState();
    }
```

I've tried to measure performance of line-by-line calls and found that recorder.swapBuffers() takes around 10 ms on Nexus 7.  Moving buffers could take that much time, which I think is reasonable.  Another one takes longer than expected was recorder.makeCurrent(), which takes around another 10 ms.

I was also trying to measure the call intervals of onDrawFrame().  When recording was off (with recordThisFrame() setting to be false), I've been consistently getting 16.7 ~ 17 ms, which is expected.  When recordThisFrame() is set to alternate between true and false to record every other frame, I've been getting around 22 ~ 25 ms (when recording) and 4~10 ms.  Even after changing the drawFrame() call to simple glclear(), I got the same result.  I tried this on Android Breakout Recorder (fadden's original code), and got the same result as well.

I was trying the "Record GL app with FBO" activity in Grafika, and I found it gets more consistent 16-17 ms intervals even with the recordings.  I was tempted to replace GLSurfaceView with SurfaceView as in the Record GL app in Grafika, but that change does not seems to be a viable option for now.

Is the makeCurrent() call that much costly?  Is there anyone experiencing similar interval issues?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: The cost of `eglMakeCurrent()` varies, but you're generally better off not switching contexts. It can be difficult to measure GLES overhead because the rendering is asynchronous until you fill up the queue of buffers and get back-pressure from the compositor. (cf. https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#stuffing) The most accurate & complete timing info comes from systrace (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html). Make sure you're actively moving your finger around the screen when taking timings -- qcom devices throttle clocks aggressively.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions fadden!  I've tried it again this time with systrace, and the results are very similar: ondrawframe() call interval is fluctuating.  Is EGLContext switching that much expensive?  Is there anyway I can modify GLSurfaceView's EGLContext so that I can share with my recording surface?

Comment: The way you fix GLSurfaceView is to not use GLSurfaceView. Note that GLSurfaceView does not need to be part of the app framework; it does nothing that your app can't. You can pull the source code out of git and stick a modified version in your app. Performance-wise, my Nexus 4 was unable to keep up with recording Android Breakout if I took my finger off the screen for a couple of seconds, so you always want to be actively using the touch screen whenever you do timings of any kind to get consistent results.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insight fadden.  Will try your suggestions!